# Differently aligned Save and Cancel button in debug edit page Summer 16

Tags: bug, debug, summer-16

In a **Summer 16 org** i'm seeing some UI changes at least in **Edit trace flag screen**.

When i edit user trace flags for my user I see the Cancel button is left aligned and Save is right aligned (They have changed there places ;))

It is just not matching the standard Salesforce theme where Save is always right and Cancel is left.

[image: Summer 16 edit trace flag snap]

**In previous release it was just opposite.**

[image]

**Questions:**

1. So is there any particular reason behind this change or it's a UI bug??
2. If it's a bug, other then raising a case, is there any way to notify salesforce support by adding any tag which they generally look for in the community like [gack](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/gack/info).

I know it's not a big issue but i just edit my trace flag and hit the Cancel button.(They are playing with my mind :D )

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me :).And I am on same boat...

Comment: @MohithShrivastava actually i hit the cancel twice in a row :D

Comment: I have also face the same issue. Clicked on cancel añd checking why it does not update